# Setting Up a Language-Switching Button in Django

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and would like some advice on how to set up a single language switching button to switch between two languages (English and Japanese in this case), and specifically how to set up this functionality in a view and access it from a template.

In the template, I've arrived at the following which works but it includes repeated code for the form and the button, which obviously isn't great.

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% ifequal LANGUAGE_CODE 'en' %}
    <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post" id="form_{{ 'ja' }}" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
        <input name="language" type="hidden" value="{{ 'ja' }}" />
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" type="submit" form="form_{{ 'ja' }}" value="Submit">日本語</button>
{% else %}
    <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post" id="form_{{ 'en' }}" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
        <input name="language" type="hidden" value="{{ 'en' }}" />
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" type="submit" form="form_{{ 'en' }}" value="Submit">English</button>
{% endifequal %}
```

My apologies for the beginner question but I'd really appreciate some advice as to how to put the above logic into a view and access it from the template. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at this post https://brainstorm.it/snippets/django-language-switching/

Comment: Thanks, cizario. That post included some good hints. I ended up setting up a custom filter which is then called on LANGUAGE_CODE to send one language code or the other to the view. It's now looking a lot better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is useful to anyone, I solved this problem as follows using a custom filter included in a file I called language_selector.py.

In language_selector.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def new_lang_code(current_lang_code):
    if current_lang_code == ‘en’:
        return ‘ja’
    else:
        return ‘en’

@register.filter
def new_lang_name(current_lang_code):
    if current_lang_code == ‘en’:
        return ‘日本語’
    else:
        return ‘English’
```

Set up a template tags directory containing the above file.

```
app/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        language_selector.py
    views.py
```

In the template:

```
{% load language_selector %}

⋮

<form action=“{% url ‘set_language’ %}” method=“post” id=“form_{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|new_lang_code }}” >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name=“next” type=“hidden” value=“{{ redirect_to }}” />
    <input name=“language” type=“hidden” value=“{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|new_lang_code }}” />
</form>
<button class=“btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary” type=“submit” form=“form_{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|new_lang_code }}” value=“Submit”>{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|new_lang_name }}</button>
```

This works and seems to be a simple and clean way to implement a language-switching button, but any comments are welcome if there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add flag pictures to your static/img/en.png etc.
2. Add this path to and only to your GLOBAL urls.py

```python
path("i18n/", include("django.conf.urls.i18n")),
```

3. Check in your settings, that USE_I18N = True and add this line to your MIDDLEWARE variable in your settings.py

```python
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
```

4. Ensure [that you have](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/) your .po (and .mo ?) files for japanese and {% translate "Hello" %} in your template.
5. This form works like in an example, but uses several flag buttons and less code. No code duplicates. Add into your template (menu template, for example?)

```html
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
<input name="language" type="hidden" value="" id="language">
{% for language in languages %}
<input type="image" class="flag" src="{% static 'img/'|add:language|add:'.png' as image_static %}" alt="{{language}}"
onmouseover="document.getElementById('language').value='{{language}}'">
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

- set_language url and function is in the i18n
- you should pass languages via your context to this template like:

```python
 context['languages'] = ['en', 'ja']
```